# Add Specific Object to a Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, object, binary-tree

I'm looking to add an object called "player" to a binary search tree based on how high the score of the player is, essentially like a scoreboard, but I'm not entirely certain how to add players to the binary tree; I'm curious how to go about writing the method, so I hope this question makes sense.

Here's a part of my BinaryTree class:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class BinaryTree implements Iterable<Player> {

private BinNode root;

public BinaryTree() {
    root = null;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return root == null;
}

// TODO: add the given player to the binary tree based on the player's game score
public void add(final Player player) {

    if (isEmpty())
        root = new BinNode(player);
    // this is SUUUPER placeholder

} ...
```

Here's the player class, :

```
public class Player implements Comparable<Player> {

private String name;
private int    score;
private static final int MIN_SCORE = 0;

public Player(final String name, int score) {
    this.name = name;
    if (score < MIN_SCORE)
        this.score = 0;
    else
        this.score = score;
}

public Player(final String name) {
    this(name, MIN_SCORE);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getScore() {
    return score;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name + ": " + score;
}

// TODO: compare player objects based on their scores
@Override
public int compareTo(Player other) {

    return score - other.score;// I think this is a step in the right direction???
}
```

}

Here's my Binary Node class:

```
public class BinNode {

private Player player;
private BinNode left, right;

public BinNode() {
    player = null;
    left = right = null;
}

public BinNode(final Player player) {
    this.player = player;
    left = right = null;
}

public Player getPlayer() {
    return player;
}

public BinNode getLeft() {
    return left;
}

public BinNode getRight() {
    return right;
}

public void setPlayer(final Player data) {
    this.player = player;
}

public void setLeft(BinNode left) {
    this.left = left;
}

public void setRight(BinNode right) {
    this.right = right;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return player.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: Have you researched how an insertion in a binary tree works? It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Do you have to implement your own Binary Search Tree? If not, I would suggest you go with java's TreeMap or TreeList. Both use an optimization to the Binary Search Tree - the Red-Black Tree. Those trees are self-balancing, like AVL trees, but not as strict. This results in an performance improvement to O(log(n)) for all insertions, removals, and searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you not to use your own trees in production, but if you are just learn, then that's fine. To add a new entity to your tree, you have to find a place for it. In this code we search for it by comparing scores of players.

```
public void add(final Player player){
    if (isEmpty()){
        root = new BinNode(player);
    }
    else{
        BinNode node = root;
        while (true){
            if (player.getScore() <= node.getPlayer().getScore()){
                if (node.getLeft() == null){
                    node.getLeft() = new BinNode(player);
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    node = node.getLeft();
                }
            }
            else{
                if (node.getRight() == null){
                    node.getRight() = new BinNode(player);
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    node = node.getRight();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```